# Is there a difference between `static_cast<bool>(x)` and `x != 0.0`?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, warnings

### The Setup

I'm working with the API for an application called MotionBuilder. In order to access a MotionBuilder property's value, you read it into a double variable, regardless of what sort of data type it actually represents.

Here's a utility function I wrote to evaluate the value of a scalar property:

```
template <typename DataT>
inline DataT GetScalar(FBProperty& prop, FBEvaluateInfo* evaluateInfo)
{
    double data = 0.0;
    prop.GetData(&data, sizeof(data), evaluateInfo);
    return static_cast<DataT>(data);
}
```

This way, I can write `GetScalar<float>(camera.Roll, evaluateInfo)` or `GetScalar<bool>(camera.Visibility, evaluateInfo)` instead of having a multiple-line mess of uninitialized buffers and casts littering my code.

I'm compiling in Visual Studio with `/W4` and addressing all warnings as they come up. When I use `GetScalar<bool>`, the compiler produces [a C4800 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
'double' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
```

When the compiler creates `GetScalar<bool>`, it winds up with a static_cast from double to bool, which it apparently doesn't like. Since my original aim was to handle multiple types (bool, float, double, etc) with a single template function, I can't just add in the usual `!= 0.0`.

In order to address this warning, I have two options.

### Option 1

I can suppress the warning directly with pragmas, since the cast is doing exactly what I wanted it to do:

```
template <typename DataT>
inline DataT GetScalar(FBProperty& prop, FBEvaluateInfo* evaluateInfo)
{
    double data = 0.0;
    prop.GetData(&data, sizeof(data), evaluateInfo);
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable: 4800) // Don't complain about casting to bool
    return static_cast<DataT>(data);
#pragma warning (pop)
}
```

### Option 2

I can add a specialization of `GetScalar` to handle the `bool` case:

```
template <>
inline bool GetScalar<bool>(FBProperty& prop, FBEvaluateInfo* evaluateInfo)
{
    double data = 0.0;
    prop.GetData(&data, sizeof(data), evaluateInfo);
    return data != 0.0;
}
```

### The Question

I would think that for some double x, `static_cast<bool>(x)` is exactly equivalent to `x != 0.0`. In fact, a simple test compiled in release mode gives me the same assembly output in both cases. Why, then, does C4800 call itself a "performance warning?" Are the two options outlined above functionally identical? If it comes down to a matter of style, after putting on your best pedant hat, which option do you prefer?

Comment: Another option is `!!x` which returns `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a **warning**, and it's telling you that there might be a performance issue for this conversion. Since you want to do the conversion, just do it. Don't waste time writing elaborate workarounds for warnings that aren't telling you anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

I do think that for the case of `bool`, comparison to 0 is more readable than a cast. I would also question whether it semantically makes sense to have a function which can be specialised for numeric types and `bool` with the same  implementation, even if that happens to work here.

Generally. In your particular case, I think having a uniform template is fine, and if it avoids code duplication, that’s an advantage. If anything, I would probably only create a function specialisation for the cast-to-`DataT` part, not the whole function:

```
template <typename T>
T convertTo(double d) { return static_cast<T>(d); }

template <>
double convertTo<bool>(double d) { return d != 0.0; }

template <typename DataT>
inline DataT GetScalar(FBProperty& prop, FBEvaluateInfo* evaluateInfo)
{
    double data = 0.0;
    prop.GetData(&data, sizeof(data), evaluateInfo);
    return convertTo<DataT>(data);
}
```

Or you could selectively disable the warning, but if you do so, explain in a comment **why** this is necessary here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the best solution for your particular setup is (I think static-casting to `bool` is perfectly fine), but a generic way to handle branching is to create separate traits for each individual operation. In your case, that's "convert_to_bool":

```
template <typename Out>
struct converter
{
    static Out from_double(double x)
    {
        return static_cast<Out>(x);
    }
};

template <>
struct converter<bool>
{
    static bool from_double(double x)
    {
        return x != 0;
    }
};
```

Now you can use:

```
return converter<DataT>::from_double(data);
```

This way you can handle every situation that crops up in your main template and requires special treatment for certain types without ever having to branch your main template.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare cases where I would use the functional-notation version of the cast, rather than `static_cast`. The compiler will not give any warnings, because this form of cast effectively tells it that you 'know what you're doing'.

```
template <typename DataT>
inline DataT GetScalar(FBProperty& prop, FBEvaluateInfo* evaluateInfo)
{
    double data = 0.0;
    prop.GetData(&data, sizeof(data), evaluateInfo);
    return DataT(data);
}
```

In general, beware of using this type of cast in C++, because it can suppress meaningful warnings. I would only use it to suppress warnings when casting between arithmetic types (e.g. `int`, `double`, `enum`), when I don't care about handling overflow.